# How do I set JVM heap size for TestNG in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, testng

I am trying to give more memory to a TestNG test with VM parameter:

[image]

But when test starts, it overrides my parameter with another one:

[image]

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overriding value was coming from pom.xml:

[image]